# Ruby variables with same object id

Tags: ruby, search

I have a problem with that piece of code.

```
temp_state = @state
```

What I want to do is to assign the values of my instance variable @state to a new local variable temp_state. The problem is that when I do

```
temp_state.object_id = 70063255838500
state.object_id = 70063255838500
```

When I modify temp_state I'm modifying also the @state. How can I work with temp_state without modifying the contents of @state?

Here are the important parts of the class:

```
class SearchNode
  attr_accessor :state, :g, :f, :free_index

  def initialize(state, parent = self)
    @state = state
    @g = parent == self ? 1 : parent.g
    @h = calculate_h
    @f = @g + @h
    @valid_action = ["Move(Black)", "Move(Red)", "Jump(Black)", "Jump(Red)"]
    @free_index = index_of_free
    @parent = parent
  end

  def move_black_jump
    free = @free_index
    # PROBLEM NEXT LINE
    temp_state = @state
    if temp_state[free + 2] == 'B' || temp_state[free - 2] == 'B'
      if free - 2 >= 0 && free + 2 <= temp_state.length
        index = free - 2 if temp_state[free - 2] == 'B'
        index = free + 2 if temp_state[free + 2] == 'B'
      else
        puts "ERROR: Movement out of bounds."
      end
        x = temp_state[index]
        temp_state[index] = 'F'
        temp_state[free] = x
     else
       puts "ERROR: Wrong movement move_black_jump."
     end
     return temp_state
   end

end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: At least two of the answers note that `dup` makes a 'shallow' copy of its receiver.  If you or other readers don't understand the significance of the qualifier 'shallow', these two examples may help: `a=[1,2,3]; b=a.dup #=>[1,2,3]; a[1]='cat' #a=>[1,"cat",3], b=>[1,2,3]` but if `a=[1,[2,3]]; b=a.dup #=>[1,[2,3]]; a[0]='dog'; a[1] ='cat' # a=>["dog",[2,"cat"], b=>[1,[2,"cat"]]`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make copy of the object, instead of passing to new variable reference to the same object. You make (shallow) copy with [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) method:

```
temp_state = @state.dup
```

Comment: Explicit pointers exist in Ruby? I always thought they were just references to their values

Answer (score 1):

When you assign variables in ruby to another variable it is pointing to first, which you've found out here. In Ruby there are many ways to get around this. One is the .dup method which makes a shallow copy of the first variable and not just a reference.  Check out he docs here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup

Answer (score 1):

You want to `temp_state = @state.dup` but that doesn't work on all objects, ie. Fixnums.